# How to display progressbar during copy

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Hi I have C# form which provided with button and picturebox

this button have main job which is (open dialog to choose file) after that this file will be copy to specific folder

if this file was huge I need my form display progress bar and increase until file copied "How I can do that"

Comment: 0% on 7 questions? Ouch.

Comment: **Hashim Al-Arab**, if an answer helps you solve your problem, please click on the big tick to the left of the answer.   This will help others in the future and rewards those who answer.

Answer (score 3):

See the [System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) class, and its associated example in the documentation. You'll likely end up using the BackgroundWorker component for this too. Here's an article with [example usage](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/12/The-BackgroundWorker-component.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you can use BackgroundWorker for that.
There are plenty of samples that show just what you want to do.

Comment: I've used this one from time to time, hopefully this can be of some assistance http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Answer (score 1):

`ShFileOperation` with `FO_COPY` and the `FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS` flag.

You would need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx) to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP doesn't know how to use P/Invoke.

Comment: I've used this solution in the past, seems so much easier than rolling your own with the Background worker.  Good resource here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHFileOperation